# How to place two proof trees next to each other with a symbol in between?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, logic

I have to typeset a transformation rule for proof trees, created with the `bussproofs` package. What I need is an implication sign between two proof trees - aligned with the horizontal separation lines of the trees - with exactly the same spacing to the left and right.

By changing the widths of the minipages and using a label in the first proof tree, I have more or less achieved the desired result, but it really is a kind of cheating.

Is there a durable solution?

[image: Transformation]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bussproofs}
\newcommand{\necc}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\Box}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.3 \textwidth}
    \begin{prooftree}
      \AxiomC{$\phi_1\,\cdots\,\phi_n$}
      \RightLabel{$\qquad\implies\qquad$}
      \UnaryInfC{$\psi$}
    \end{prooftree}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.25\textwidth}
    \begin{prooftree}
      \AxiomC{$\necc\phi_1\,\cdots\,\necc\phi_n$}
      \UnaryInfC{$\necc\psi$}
    \end{prooftree}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put in-line proof trees into a `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}% standalone doesn't support centering
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bussproofs}
\newcommand{\necc}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\Box}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \AxiomC{$\phi_1\,\cdots\,\phi_n$}
    \RightLabel{$\qquad\implies\qquad$}
    \UnaryInfC{$\psi$}
    \DisplayProof
    \AxiomC{$\necc\phi_1\,\cdots\,\necc\phi_n$}
    \UnaryInfC{$\necc\psi$}
    \DisplayProof
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

You can even use an `equation` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bussproofs}
\newcommand{\necc}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\Box}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \AxiomC{$\phi_1\,\cdots\,\phi_n$}
    \UnaryInfC{$\psi$}
    \DisplayProof
    \quad\implies\quad
    \AxiomC{$\necc\phi_1\,\cdots\,\necc\phi_n$}
    \UnaryInfC{$\necc\psi$}
    \DisplayProof
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```